# Container similar to Android's ArrayMap in C++

Tags: android, c++, dictionary, stl, memory-efficient

Android provides an associative container named [`ArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html), which is implemented with two simple arrays.

This container is supposed to be somewhat slower than other data structures, especially when inserting data, but it is very memory-efficient.

Is there such thing already implemented in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost's [`flat_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) and EASTL's [`vector_map`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) seem to be the analogues of `ArrayMap`.